# Create a directory with the specific name

Tags: php, mysqli

I am making gallery website using PHP and Mysqli and I have an image uploader screen with the option to select multiple images, title the project, etc. What is the code for creating a new directory (in "images/projects/") on the server with the name of the project's title? So that all the files selected were saved into the new folder that has a name of "imageTitle" field.

html:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post"
      enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <label for="image">Select a file:</label>
    <input type="file" name="image[]" id="image" multiple />
    <br /><br>
    <label for="picname">Title:</label>
    <input type="text" name="picname" id="picname" />
    <br /><br>
    <label for="picdesc">Description:</label>
    <input type="text" name="picdesc" id="picdesc" />
    <br /><br>
    <label for="piccat">Category:</label>
    <select name="piccat" id="piccat">
        <option value="--"></option>
        <option value="animation">Animation</option>
        <option value="illustration">Illustration</option>
        <option value="photography">Photography</option>
    </select>
    <br /><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

php:

```
<?php
$path = "images/projects/";
include("check.php");
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES["image"]["name"]); $i++) {
        $image = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"][$i];
        $imageName = $_FILES["image"]["name"][$i];
        $imageSize = $_FILES["image"]["size"][$i];
        $imageType = $_FILES["image"]["type"][$i];
        $imageTitle = $_POST["picname"];
        $imageDescription = $_POST["picdesc"];
        $imageCategory = $_POST["piccat"];
        $path = $path . $imageName;
        $imageFileType = pathinfo($path,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        $query = $db -> prepare("INSERT INTO images 
            (user_id, image, description, type, title, size, category) 
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $query -> bind_param('issssis', $_SESSION['user_id'], 
            $imageName, $imageDescription, $imageType, 
            $imageTitle, $imageSize, $imageCategory);
        $query -> execute();
        $query -> close();

        if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" 
            && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
            && $imageFileType != "gif" && $imageFileType != "mp4") {
            echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG, MP4 & GIF files are allowed.";
        }
        if ($imageName){
            move_uploaded_file($image, $path);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You can make a new folder with `mkdir(<folder name>)`.

Comment: Are you looking for [mkdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php)? Wouldn't it be quicker just to search google for `php create folder`?

Comment: Yes but how can I integrate it into my code? Is it something like mkdir($path . $imageTitle, 0700) ?I am very new to php so it's still kind of hard for me ...